# Adding multiple items on cart (add to cart) in e-commerce website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am having a problem in storing multiple ids in my code. I need the ids to be saved on a single variable (array) because I will call it in cart.php to show the items that were added to the cart. Here are my codes.

```html
<!--This is the android.php where you can browse the items to be added to the cart -->
<?php
include('php/userloginprocess.php'); // Includes Login Script

if($_SESSION['login'] == FALSE){
 header("location: login.php");
}
if($_SESSION['login'] == TRUE)
?>
<!Document HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Marketech | Buy Genuine Gadgets Online | Android Phones</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/marketechlogo.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- First Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Marketech</a>
    </div>
<?php
//connection
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("marketech_db") or die(mysql_error());
//query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tbl";
$records=mysql_query($sql);
while($users=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
}
?>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="cart.php"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $_SESSION ['fname']; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="useraccountsettings.php">Account Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="php/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Second Navigation Bar -->
<br><br><br>
<div class = "container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-lower">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
    </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-12">
        <li class="active col-md-2"><a href="android.php">Samsung</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="iphone.php">Apple</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="windows.php">Microsoft</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="smartwatch.php">Smart Watch</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="computer.php">Computers</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown col-xs-2"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other Popular Brands <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-2"> 
    <li><a href="sony.php">Sony</a></li>
    <li><a href="asus.php">Asus</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Marketechs Third Navigation (with glyphicons) -->
<div class="container-fluid">
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> 30 days Free Returns</li>
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Free Delivery Above 999 php</li>
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Cash on Delivery</li>
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Call (049) 557 2681</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="col-md-0 col-md-offset-0">
 <div class="container">
  <div class = "col-md-14">
 <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel1" data-ride"carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item active">
    <img src = "images/androidbanner1.jpg"> 
    <div class = "carousel-caption">
     <h4> Samsung J1 Mini Prime</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <img src = "images/androidbanner2.jpg"> 
    <div class = "carousel-caption">
     <h4>Samsung S7</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#carousel1" data-slide="prev" class = "left carousel-control"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a href="#carousel1" data-slide="next" class = "right carousel-control"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- Items Division -->
 <center><h2 id="samsung"><b>Samsung</b></h2></center>
  <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_tbl where brand = 'samsung' AND type ='android'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    
    <p class = "col-md-4"><a href = "#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src = "uploaded_images/<?php echo $row['item_image']?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target = "#modal<?php echo $row['prod_id'] ?>">
    </a>
    <a href = "#" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#modal<?php echo $row['prod_id']?>">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font color = "black"><?php echo $row['item_name']?>
    </a>
    <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Price: <?php echo $row['item_price']?> Php</p>
<!-- Footer Navigation -->
<!-- Modal Locations -->
<!-- Start of the First Modal (SAMSUNG J1 MINI)-->

<div class = "modal fade" id = "modal<?php echo $row['prod_id']?>">
 <div class = "modal-dialog">
  <div class = "modal-content">
   <div class = "modal-header">
    <p> <?php echo $row['item_name']?> </p>
   </div>
   <div class = "modal-body">
    <p class = "col-md-12"><b>Specifications</b>
    <ul class = "list-unstyled col-md-12">
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Display:</font></b><?php echo$row['display']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Resolution:</font></b><?php echo$row['resolution']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Storage:</font></b> <?php echo$row['storage']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">RAM:</font></b> <?php echo$row['ram']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Front Cam:</font></b><?php echo$row['frontcam']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Rear Cam:</font></b><?php echo$row['rearcam']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">OS:</font></b><?php echo$row['os']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Processor:</font></b><?php echo$row['processor']?></center></li>
     <li class = "col-md-12"><center><b><font color = "green">Battery Capacity:</font></b><?php echo$row['battery']?></center></li>
    </ul>
    <div class = "zoom_img">
        
    <center><img class = "img-responsive" src = "uploaded_images/<?php echo $row['item_image']?>"></center>
    </p></div> 
   </div>
   <div class = "modal-footer">
  <form method = "GET" action = "php/addtocartprocess.php">
    <p>Price: <?php echo $row['item_price']?><br>
    
     <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $row["prod_id"];?>">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></form>
    
    </p>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php
 }
?>
<!-- End of Modal Locations -->
<!-- footer -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class ="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
  <ul class ="list-unstyled">
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b>Call Us: (049) 557 2681</b></h5></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "about.php"><font color = "black">About Us </b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "contact.php"><font color = "black">Contact Us</b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "privacy.php"><font color = "black">Privacy</b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "terms.php"><font color = "black">Terms of Service</b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b>Copyright (c) 2016<h5></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
<!-- 
Members:
Marlon Mendoza
-->
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- Here's my addtocartprocess.php where the ids are stored-->
<?php
*if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(isset($_GET['add_to_cart'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['product_id']);
    header("location: ../android.php?id=" . $_GET['product_id'] . "");
}

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

```html
<!-- This is the cart.php it shows the items that were added to the cart. My problem is I can't call the items in the cart. Sometimes it is working but it can only store one id so if you clicked another item and add it to the cart the previous item that you selected will be removed to the cart-->
<?php
include('php/userloginprocess.php'); // Includes Login Script
include('php/addtocartprocess.php');
$prod_id = $_SESSION['cart'];
/*$id = $_SESSION['prod_id'];
$gadgets = $_SESSION['prod_id'];*/
if($_SESSION['login'] == FALSE){
 header("location: login.php");
}
if($_SESSION['login'] == TRUE)
?>
<?php
//connection
mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die(mysql_error());
//database connection
mysql_select_db("marketech_db") or die(mysql_error());
//sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tbl";
$records=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Marketech | Buy Genuine Gadgets Online </title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/marketechlogo.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- First Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Marketech</a>
    </div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $_SESSION ['fname']; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="useraccountsettings.php">Account Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="php/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Second Navigation Bar -->
<br><br><br>
<div class = "container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-lower">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-12">
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="android.php">Android Phone</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="iphone.php">iPhone</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="windows.php">Windows Phone</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="smartwatch.php">Smart Watch</a></li>
        <li class="col-md-2"><a href="computer.php">Computers</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown col-md-2"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Popular Brands <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-2"> 
    <li><a href="android.php#samsung">Samsung</a></li>
    <li><a href="iphone.php">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="windows.php">Microsoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="android.php#sony">Sony</a></li>
    <li><a href="android.php#asus">Asus</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Marketechs Third Navigation (with glyphicons) -->
<div class="container">
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> 30 days Free Returns</li>
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Free Delivery Above 999 php</li>
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Cash on Delivery</li>
   <li class = "col-md-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Call (049) 557 2681</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Cart -->

<div class = "container-fluid">
<form method = "GET" action = "deletecartproduct.php">
 <div class = "col-md-9">
  <table class = "table table-responsive table-hover">
   <tr>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Item Price</th>
    <th>Image</th>
   </tr>
<?php
//connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("marketech_db") or die (mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_tbl WHERE prod_id  IN (".implode(',',$prod_id).")";
$prod_records = mysql_query($sql);
while($products=mysql_fetch_assoc($prod_records)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo  "<td>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value='.$products['prod_id'].'>'."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$products['item_name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$products['item_price']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$products['item_image']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
  </table>
  <input type ="submit" class = "btn btn-danger" name = "delete_cart_item" value = "Delete"></form>
 </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<!-- Footer Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
  <ul class ="list-unstyled">
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b>Call Us: (049) 557 2681</b></h5></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "about.php"><font color = "black">About Us </b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "contact.php"><font color = "black">Contact Us</b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "privacy.php"><font color = "black">Privacy</b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b><a href = "terms.php"><font color = "black">Terms of Service</b></h5></font></a></li>
   <li class = "col-md-2"><h5><b>Copyright (c) 2016<h5></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- 
Members:
Marlon Mendoza
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question by using different method in retrieving ids and storing it in a multidimensional array.